# Silent install from command line with desired component?

Tags: nsis

I have a 3rd-party NSIS compiled installer with several components (3 checkbox GUI).
I'm trying to do a silent install from the command line (/S) with only one component.

Is there a way to choose the desired component from the command line?(parameters?)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to detect custom command line parameters but there is already a built-in silent check you can use:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Sections.nsh

Section Foo SID_FOO
SectionEnd
Section Bar SID_BAR
SectionEnd
Section Baz SID_BAZ
SectionEnd

Function .onInit
${If} ${Silent}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SID_FOO}
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${SID_BAR}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SID_BAZ}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: The Nullsoft exe install file is not mine. Where I should run those function?

Comment: @wizard: If the installer is not yours then this question does not belong on Stackoverflow. Only the author of the installer can implement this. They may already support it but you would have to look at their documentation or contact them directly to find out.

Comment: I have the same question about a 3rd party package for which open source is available. I would like to run the installer silently with options to pre-select the Components to select. Where would I look in the package's source to tell what options to specify?

Comment: @Codex24 Look for $CMDLINE, ${GetParameters} or ${GetOptions} if you are interested in custom switches. Look for ${If} ${Silent} and IfSilent for things changed by /S.